# Can Google Photos sync up iOS Photos *albums*?

Tags: photos, google

Is there any way to get Google Photos sync on iOS/OS X to recognise my albums and retain those photos in those albums when on Google Photos?

I am looking for ways to return to Android.

Thanks.

Comment: With the web interface for Google photos you can upload any pictures from your computer storage. If the pictures are synchronized across your apple devices you should have a directory on your computer that contains them. Just click on the cloud with an arrow inside symbol on the right of the search bar and choose said directory as source.

Comment: Photos doesn't store files by the albums they belong to. They can't because any photo could be in multiple albums. The questioner is not trying to sync photos, he's trying to sync albums. This is the Photos equivalent of syncing iTunes playlists. It's not just about copying files. I'd like to know how to do it, too.